# jwplayer: using seek(), onTime() and stop() to play part of the video

Tags: javascript, jquery, jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am using latest JW Player cloud hosted version.

I need to seek the video to start from certain position and stop at certain position using `seek()`, `onTime()` and `stop()`.

```
jwplayer().onReady(function() { 
    jwplayer().seek(300).onTime(function(event) {
        if(event.position>330) {
            jwplayer().stop();
        }
    });
});
```

The video starts and stops with the above command, but if the user clicks on play button again, it starts from beginning instead of the time specified in `seek()`.

I have advertisement associated with this video.

Any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could try using [onBeforePlay()](http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference) method, its fired just before playing, as:

```
jwplayer('player').setup({
        ......
    });
jwplayer().onBeforePlay(function(){ 
    jwplayer().seek(300); 
});
```

Comment: That was quick... I missed onBeforePlay(), thanks
I was checking on making the progress bar start from the beginning even when we use seek(), and that will complete playing parts of a video.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when the Flash player is being used. It's likely an issue with Flash "streaming."